# 404 error in admin extension config tab as user with all privileges

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm using CE 1.9.2.0. Earlier today, I followed directions in [this Nexcess article](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-set-magento-file-permissions-and-ownership.html) for setting file permissions. There is a certain menu item in my extensions config tab that's nowthrowing 404 errors. It's a "manage items" tab for a javascript slider. I can't confirm when I was last able to successfully navigate to this menu; but I'm sure it's been no more than two or three days. Changing my file permissions is the only event coming to mind that might explain the issue.

Anyway, I've tried chmodding my files and directories back, clearing browser cache, disabling/flushing magento caches, reindexing all indices, refreshing my user role (i have "all" access), logging out/logging in, checking system.log and exception.log - nothing relevant in either of those. I've tried disabling the extension in question and reenabling it. This 404 will not yield!

I've seen some evidence that users with less than "all" permissions are getting 404 errors when using extension tabs with 1.9.2, but it seems that wouldn't apply to me. Or would it?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

And if there's piece of information that I can post from my installation that would help, please advise.

EDIT:

here are my two config files for the module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentothem_Banner7>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magentothem_Banner7>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magentothem_Banner7>
            <version>1.8.0.0</version>
        </Magentothem_Banner7>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <banner7>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentothem_Banner7</module>
                    <frontName>banner7</frontName>
                </args>
            </banner7>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <banner7>
                    <file>banner7.xml</file>
                </banner7>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <banner7>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magentothem_Banner7</module>
                    <frontName>banner7</frontName>
                </args>
            </banner7>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <magentothem translate="title" module="banner7">
            <title>Magentothem</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <banner7 translate="title" module="banner7">
                    <title>Banner7</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <items translate="title" module="banner7">
                            <title>Manage Items</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <action>banner7/adminhtml_banner7</action>
                        </items>
                        <configuration>
                            <title>Configuration</title>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/banner7</action>
                        </configuration>
                    </children>
                </banner7>
            </children>
        </magentothem>
    </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Magentothem_Banner7>
                            <title>Banner7 Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </Magentothem_Banner7>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <banner7>
                    <file>banner7.xml</file>
                </banner7>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>   
    <global>
        <models>
            <banner7>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>banner7_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </banner7>
            <banner7_mysql4>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <banner7>
                        <table>banner7</table>
                    </banner7>
                </entities>
            </banner7_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <banner7_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Magentothem_Banner7</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </banner7_setup>
            <banner7_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </banner7_write>
            <banner7_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </banner7_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <banner7>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Block</class>
            </banner7>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <banner7>
                <class>Magentothem_Banner7_Helper</class>
            </banner7>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <banner7>
            <banner7_config>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <animation>sliceDown</animation>
                <speed>5000</speed>
                <interval>600</interval>
                <qty_item>4</qty_item>
                <description>0</description>
                <next_back>0</next_back>
                <nav_ctrl>1</nav_ctrl>
            </banner7_config>
        </banner7>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you share the `config.xml` contents for the module? It's likely that the admin route isn't defined properly, or that the controller is in the wrong place.

Comment: Absolutely; please see edited post. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Firstly, you should see if there's an update for the extension as it is not going to work with the latest SUPEE 6788 security patch from Magento

Comment: That's for the lead, @Robbie. I applied SUPEE 6788 nearly two weeks ago, so I didn't see the connection, at first. However, reading through the release notes just now, I remembered recently disabling compatibility mode in Admin -> Security. Re-enabling that has returned the functionality of my extension. I suppose it's just a bandaid. If this should be considered an answer, I'll repost it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that got it sorted for you